# Clearing formats in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, power-automate

I have a Microsoft Flow sending data to a Google Sheet. When the data appears in the sheet some of the cells have a hidden apostrophe which prevents calculations and prevents some formula.

I have a script that formats the cells with number so that I can run calculations. What I am unable to do is clear the apostrophe from the cell that I want to run =NOW() so that I can create a timestamp.

I have created a script but I can't figure out how to make this cell do what I want.

```
function setFormat(){SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:A").getValue().replace("'=NOW()","=NOW()");SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2:C").setNumberFormat('000');SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D2:D").setNumberFormat('000');SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E2:E").setNumberFormat('000');SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("F2:F").setNumberFormat('000');}`
```

[image: format in cell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sample?

1. Using `getValues()`, data of "A2:A" is retrieved.
   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues
2. Data retrieved at 1 is converted from `'=NOW()` to `=NOW()`.
3. Using `setFormulas()`, converted data is imported to "A2:A".
   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas
4. `setNumberFormat()` works fine for your script.

**Sample script :**

```
function setFormat(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var Data = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var replacedData = [[i[0].replace("'=NOW()","=NOW()")] for each (i in Data) if(i[0])];
  ss.getRange(2, 1, replacedData.length, replacedData[0].length).setFormulas(replacedData);

  ss.getRange("C2:C").setNumberFormat('000');
  ss.getRange("D2:D").setNumberFormat('000');
  ss.getRange("E2:E").setNumberFormat('000');
  ss.getRange("F2:F").setNumberFormat('000');
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

**Added 1 :**

The type of `=NOW()` as a formula is object. So only `'=NOW()` as a string is converted to formula `=NOW()` by comparing the type. When you add more data, the added data will be converted.

```
function setFormat(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var Data = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var replacedData = [typeof(i[0])=="object" ? ["=NOW()"] : [i[0].replace("'=NOW()","=NOW()")] for each (i in Data) if(i[0])];
  ss.getRange(2, 1, replacedData.length, replacedData[0].length).setFormulas(replacedData);

  ss.getRange("C2:C").setNumberFormat('000');
  ss.getRange("D2:D").setNumberFormat('000');
  ss.getRange("E2:E").setNumberFormat('000');
  ss.getRange("F2:F").setNumberFormat('000');
}
```

**Added 2 :**

This sample imports date object as a string, when new data was imported.

```
function setFormat(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var Data = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var replacedData = [
      typeof(i[0])=="object"
      ? [i[0]]
      : [i[0].replace("=NOW()", Utilities.formatDate(
        new Date(),
        Session.getScriptTimeZone(),
        'yyyy/M/d HH:mm:ss')
      )
    ]
    for each (i in Data) if(i[0])
  ];
  ss.getRange(2, 1, replacedData.length, replacedData[0].length).setValues(replacedData);

  ss.getRange("C2:C").setNumberFormat('000');
  ss.getRange("D2:D").setNumberFormat('000');
  ss.getRange("E2:E").setNumberFormat('000');
  ss.getRange("F2:F").setNumberFormat('000');
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I am getting an error TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line5, file "Code")

Comment: Actually, I have run into an issue. New rows of data are imported from Microsft flow every hour. The script is running into an issue as it is stopping after the first row as it is now finding the correct date and not =NOW() so all other rows are not being updated. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can I ask you about the data? When I could know the data, I can try to find the solution.

Comment: I importing Twitter user account data - I get their name, tweets, followers etc. What I am trying to do is get a timestamp in column A whenever new data is imported. I can have the anything imported into column A - I just thought that =NOW() would work but it keeps importing it with the apostrophe. Thanks

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the data - essentially though the columns are are Twitter data for multiple accounts: Timestamp | User Account Name | Tweets | Followers | Following - the data is imported every 60 minutes and I just need a way of adding a timestamp

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike - it's nearly perfect. The only problem now is that when new data is added it is updating the previous timestamp as it is refreshing the =now() formula.

Comment: Yes. When the spreadsheet is reopened, ``=NOW()`` is also updated to current time. If you want to fix the time when data was imported, it is imported as a string. I updated my answer as Added 2, just now. Please confirm and select it for your situation.

Comment: Welcome. Thank you, too.